# How to add a PUBKEY?

Tags: ros, ros2, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello every one,

I'm really new to Ubuntu and ROS, I'm trying to install ROS2 Foxy Fitsroy  on Ubuntu 20.04 but when I want to add ROS 2 apt repository, I get an error because the public key F42ED6FBAB17C654 is not availabale.

I try to add the key using this command :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv-keys F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

But it occur an error :

```
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/... focal InRelease Hit:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease Get:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease [4 676 B] Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654 Reading package lists... Done W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654 E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I also try to add all the missing GPG Keys using Yppa but it ain't do nothing.

I haven't been able to solve the problem, that why I'm asking for some help here. I hope I be precise enough.
Thanks you in advance

Benjamin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398460/how-to-add-a-pubkey-?/) by [benj21](https://answers.ros.org/users/101047/benj21/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2022-04-04**:
See the accepted answer to [#q325039](https://answers.ros.org/question/325039/apt-update-fails-cannot-install-pkgs-key-not-working/), particularly the syntax for adding a new key which looks a little different than yours .. probably should be something like

> `sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key F42ED6FBAB17C654`

**Comment by [benj21](https://answers.ros.org/users/101047/benj21/) on 2022-04-04**:
Thanks for your answer  abhishek47  unfortunately it didn't work for me I've still have the same issue.
By using the command line you gave me, it's result in this :

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.JRQ96DR3TH/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

gpg: key F42ED6FBAB17C654: "Open Robotics info@osrfoundation.org" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

But when i update, I've still got the issue

```
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-04-06**:
You shouldn't have to manually add the key using the command you've provided.
Would you be able to update your question with the output from running the commands in [Setup Sources](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html#setup-sources)?

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-04-06**:
I'm guessing you accidentally followed instructions for an older version of ROS or ROS2.
Try running

- `sudo apt-key del F42ED6FBAB17C654` to remove the key you've added, then run
- `sudo apt update`, then
- `sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg`, then
- `echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(source /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null`

**Comment by [benj21](https://answers.ros.org/users/101047/benj21/) on 2022-04-09**:
It's worked, I've successfully install ros2 after that.
Thanks you for your help!!! :)
And by the way sorry for posting the uptade in an answer.
Also, should I delete the post now or rename it with solved or something ?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-09**:
@ijnek should write his comments as an answer for you to accept :)

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-04-10**:
@benj21 I've moved my comment to a solution, which you should be able to mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm guessing you accidentally followed instructions for an older version of ROS or ROS2. Try running

- `sudo apt-key del F42ED6FBAB17C654` to remove the key you've added, then run
- `sudo apt update`, then
- `sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg`, then
- `echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(source /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null`

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2022-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benj21](https://answers.ros.org/users/101047/benj21/) on 2022-04-10**:
Once again thanks for your help :)

**Comment by [Huawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/142727/huawei/) on 2023-03-23**:
Did not worked on my computer